# Updating array values with REACT

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I update array values with React? I create an array in a constructor and when an user clicks button it should increase my array values by 1 depending on the parameter that comes along to the method where I try to update the array. When the user clicks button then react method is called and there I have tried to use `setState` code but I'm getting an error that says that array is not defined.
I have checked with `console.log` that parameter comes to `onButtonClick` method in a correct form.

```js
this.state = { array: [0, 0] } //this is in the constructor and here I create the array

onButtonClick(animal) {
  //this method gets called when a user clicks a button and here are the ways I have tried to get my array values to be updated.
  if (animal == 'dog') {
    //this.setState({array : array[0].value + 1});
    //this.state.array[0].value = array[0].value+1;
    //this.setState({array : array[0]=array[0].value+1});
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to access the variable via `this.state.array` and make a copy of the old array before incrementing it.

```
if (animal == "dog") {
  const newArray = [...this.state.array]
  newArray[0] += 1;
  this.setState({ array: newArray })
}
```

Here I use [array spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Copy_an_array) to copy the array.

If you've only got a couple items in the array, you can use [array destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Array_destructuring) to give them meaningful names:

```
if (animal == "dog") {
  const [first, second] = this.state.array
  this.setState({ array: [first + 1, second] })
}
```

although if that is the case, you might as well be using an object instead of an array as your state.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the previous value inside the setState Function

```
onButtonClick(animal){
      if (animal == "dog"){
          this.setState((prev) => ({ ...prev, array: [prev.array[0]+ 1, ...prev.array] }))  
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to increase the first element of the array in the state. Set the new state with the array value of first element of old one increased by 1 and spread the rest.

```js
this.state = { array: [0, 0] }

onButtonClick(animal) {
  if (animal == 'dog') {
    this.setState({
      array: [this.state.array[0] + 1, ...this.state.array.slice(1)]
    })
  }
}
```