# Updating a value in a React state array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to update a very simple state array.

Here's how I am initializing the array.

```
const [total, setTotal] = useState([0,0,0]);
```

I also have an index to keep track of called, `option`

To make it simple, I just need a function that takes in 'price' as an argument and adds it to the state array named 'total'

```
const addToTotal = (price) => {setTotal(total[option] += price)}
```

I know I have to use the spread operator to update and that this is incorrect, but I hope this gives an idea of what I'm trying to do.

Edit: Sorry that there is a little confusion. When I said 'add', I want to increment the number in that specific array.

If
`option = 1` then I 'add' 1 it, the result should be [1, 0, 0]

Comment: When you say "add", do you mean the array goes from `[0, 0, 0]` to `[0, 0, 0, 1]`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add items to array in react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72225342/how-to-add-items-to-array-in-react)

Comment: See also (for the new title) [Updating array values with REACT](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62698067/215552)

Comment: It should be [1, 0, 0] and this is a functional component I am working with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing it is by using `map` to update the state

```
const addToTotal = (price) => {
    const newState = total.map((t, i) => i === option ? t + price : t)
    setTotal(newState)
)}
```

Comment: Thank you! Looks like this is the right step in finding the solution. However, I'm getting stuck with an infinite loop when I try to implement this in my code. To be more specific, it's happening when I try to do setTotal(newState)

Comment: Nevermind! There was something else that was causing the infinite loop in my code. TYSM!

Answer (score 1):

Use the callback in usestate set method

```
  const addToTotal = (price) => {
    setTotal(prev => {
     prev[option] += price
     return prev
    }
  )}
```

Comment: How many times has this question been answered? Why are you adding another one?

Comment: even though the callback concept has been answered before, the context of this question is different. The link you provided uses a spread operator; we don't need it here.

Comment: It's been asked many more times than once. If that was the wrong duplicate (because of incorrect wording in the original question), there are many more that are exactly the same, and use the same answer... Doing a small amount of searching before answering is expected of "trusted users" of the platform.